# Integral Closures and Affine Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be an irreducible affine curve with singular points, and let $A$ be its ring of regular functions.  Since $C$ has singular points, $A$ is not integrally closed in its field of fractions, $K$.  I'd like to compute $\overline{A}^K$, the integral closure of $A$ in $K$ by resolving the singularities of $C$.

Suppose by blowing up the singularities of $C$ I obtain a non-singular curve $C'$ which happens to be affine itself, and a map $C'\twoheadrightarrow C$ of varieties.  This induces an injection $A\hookrightarrow A'$, where $A'$ is the ring of regular functions of $C'$.  Since $C'$ is non-singular, $A'$ is integrally closed, and I suspect is isomorphic to $\overline{A}^K$.  To verify my suspicion, I would need to show that all elements of $A'$ are integral over $A$.

Can someone help me see why this is true or not true?  I understand that one implication of my suspicion is that if a birational equivalence class of curves has a non-singular affine curve, then it is unique up to isomorphism, but this doesn't seem so hard to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blowing-up morphism $C'\to C$ is projective by definition. It is quasi-finite because $\dim C'=1$ which excludes the possibility for the excetional locus to have positive dimension. So it is finite. This means $A\to A'$ is module-finite, hence integral.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  This is very helpful and I will do more work to understand thoroughly what you have said.  My hope is that for an explicit $C$ and $f\in A'$, this procedure will give a method of constructing a monic polynomial in $A[t]$ that vanishes at $f$ using the blowing-up morphism.

Comment: @Jared: to find explicitely the normalization of curves, I think you can use computer program as Singular, Macaulay etc (though I am not at all familiar with).

Comment: Don't worry, I will upvote/accept the answer when I understand it.  I'm not doubting its accuracy, but I've yet to have the time to sit down and work through it.  Until then I am still open to other ways of thinking about the problem.